# "tkinter.filedialog" does not recognize files without a suffix in its name

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am using `filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("All files", "*.*")])`, but for some reason, when the dialog opens, it does not show any files without a suffix. For example if there is a text file called `notes`, it would not show up in the dialog. But if I rename it to `notes.txt`, then it shows up in the list of files even though both `notes` and `notes.txt` are both text files just with a name difference.

Is there anyway to fix this? It seems really unreasonable to except the user of the program to always include the suffix in the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official documentation does not mention it, but if you want to get the files with or without an extension you will need to change:

```
askopenfilename(filetypes=[("All files", "*.*")])
```

To:

```
askopenfilename(filetypes=[("All files", "*")])
```

## Proof:

Here is a simple code to demonstrate the above statement:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

f_options = dict(filetypes=[('All files','*')])

class Begueradj(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title('Begueradj Test All Files')
        menu = self.menubar = Menu(self)
        fmenu = self.filemenu = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
        menu.add_cascade(label='File', underline=0, menu=fmenu)
        fmenu.add_command(label="Open", underline=0,
                          accelerator='Ctrl+O',
                          command=self.fopendialog)
        self.config(menu=menu)
        self.bind_all('<Control-o>', self.fopendialog)

    def fopendialog(self, event=None):
        print repr(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=self,
                                                **f_options))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Begueradj()
    test.mainloop()
```

## Demo:

Here is a screenshot of the above program:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.